# How to publish a pose in quaternion?

Tags: ros, pose, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have all the values for point`(x, y, z)` and quaternion `(w, qx, qy, qz)`. Do I just make a dict and publish it as a Pose topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316829/how-to-publish-a-pose-in-quaternion?/) by [paul_shuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37881/paul_shuvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to [create a publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) and publish a [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

def publisher():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('pose', Pose, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('pose_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(2) # Hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        p = Pose()
        p.position.x = 0.5
        p.position.y = -0.1
        p.position.z = 1.0
        # Make sure the quaternion is valid and normalized
        p.orientation.x = 0.0
        p.orientation.y = 0.0
        p.orientation.z = 0.0
        p.orientation.w = 1.0
        pub.publish(p)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        publisher()
    except rospy:
        pass
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-27**:
To add: see [rospy/Overview/Messages](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Messages) for some other styles of msg initialisation in `rospy`.

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2019-12-12**:
you should edit your answer to -->> `p.orientation.y = 0.0` and `p.orientation.z = 0.0`